# How to connect to MS SQL Server with F# with SQLProvider?

Tags: .net, sql-server, f#

I'm trying to use the [SQLProvider for MS SQL Server with F#](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/mssql.html#Using-Microsoft-Data-SqlClient-dll-instead-of-build-in-System-Data-SqlClient-dll), but it appears that it's not possible with the recommended setup.

See my module below:

```ml
namespace MyApp

open FSharp.Data.Sql

module Database =

    [<Literal>]
    let dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER


    [<Literal>]
    let connString =
        "Data Source=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=user;Password='my-password-here'"

    [<Literal>]
    let indivAmount = 1000

    [<Literal>]
    let useOptTypes = true

    type sql = SqlDataProvider<dbVendor, connString, IndividualsAmount=indivAmount, UseOptionTypes=useOptTypes>
```

My main problem is that after adding in this code I get this message/warning in intellisense

> The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.F# Compiler(3033)

and a build error when attempting to compile:

```sh
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
C:\Development\F#\MyApp\DataTypes.fs(21,16): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform. [C:\Development\F#\MyApp\MyApp.fsproj]
C:\Development\F#\MyApp\DataTypes.fs(21,16): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform. [C:\Development\F#\MyApp\MyApp.fsproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Development\F#\MyApp\DataTypes.fs(21,16): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform. [C:\Development\F#\MyApp\MyApp.fsproj]
C:\Development\F#\MyApp\DataTypes.fs(21,16): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform. [C:\Development\F#\MyApp\MyApp.fsproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:06.21
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong, or is this really just not possible to use the default setup along with latest .NET and F# and I need to submit a git issue? Any insights and critiques welcomed, thanks!

In use at the time of posting:

- .NET 6
- VS Code (1.62.2)
- Ionide (v5.9.0)
- SQLProvider Version 1.2.10
- System.Data.SqlClient Version 4.8.3

Comment: Not an answer, but did you try "Using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll instead of build-in System.Data.SqlClient.dll" as outlined in the linked page?

Comment: Not exactly, I tried including that as a reference, but that's the most I've done. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft would you happen to know how to link the dll the way they want? The documentation is rather vague in that regard, ie *just do X* without really showing how. A link to more thorough explanation would be good to.

Comment: Download the nuget package from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/  then rename it to add a `.zip` extension and extract the .dll's.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft do I just put the dll anywhere in the F# proj and use where it gets placed post compilation (or location within the project) in the **ResolutionPath**?

Comment: That I have no idea about.

Comment: Why resolve dependencies by downloading files why not just use
`dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`
in the project folder.

Comment: @masoodahm do you know how to get the nuget package to work? My initial approach was to do just that, but I either get a "null error occurred" or "System.Data.SqlClient is not supported" message. Must be some other setup needed or it's broken for .NET 6 + F# 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I opened the project within Visual Studio (v17 2022) and did the following:

- removed dependencies
- added back in SQLProvider and System.Data.SqlClient (v4.8.3)
- cleared out bin and obj folders

After doing the above I was able to run the application and get a connection to the database followed by a simple select query that returned expected data.

Not sure why, but Ionide always gives the dreaded *red squigglies* even when things build just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run from command line:
`dotnet add package microsoft.data.sqlclient`

then change `Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER` to `Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER_DYNAMIC`

Comment: This did not work for me, it fails to load required resources and won't compile with an FS3033 error on `SqlDataProvider` any ideas on why or how to resolve that?

Comment: I think the issue stems from VS Code using dotnet instead of msbuild. Apparently the way they integrated sqlclient just doesn't work with dotnet build/run/etc. I've been at this for a month and couldn't figure it out.